# How to remove the noise without destroying the main edge?

Tags: image-processing, filters, noise, opencv, denoising

I am working on a project. I want to segment a logo from a car and the picture's size is 3648*2432. The logo is selected by the red rectangle.

[image]

I extracted this area and turn into gray level. The area's size is 249*173. Then, I use histogram equalize to enhance the edge. Finally, I use adaptive canny to find edge.

[image] 
[image]

However, the result is not perfect.
So, I used median filter to smooth the left picture. The result is as following.

[image]

I remove the small parts.

[image]

The result has been improved, but it is also not good. Besides, I have tried  bilateral filter, mean filter and Gaussian filter, but the result is not good, too. I know that after passing histogram equalize, the noise can be enhance. But, in some case, low contrast, I need to adapt this step to enhance my picture. Is any one who can provide me any different comment? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [bilateral filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) or [anisotropic diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion) first.

The effect of anisotropic diffusion is as the following:

[image]. The MATLAB code can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14995-anisotropic-diffusion--perona---malik-).

Here is its effect on your image:
[image]

Finally, [non-local means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-local_means) is a also a good way to get rid of the noise. You might also want to take a look into that. I warn you though, it is slow.

Comment: Have a try on this: https://github.com/RoyiAvital/Fast-Anisotropic-Curvature-Preserving-Smoothing Much more advanced than the Classic Anisotropic Diffusion.

Comment: @tbirdal: anisotropic diffusion seems interesting, if you can you provide a set of original and processed image examples together with generating matlab code, that would be appreciated.

Comment: check again please.

Comment: Thank you for the examples and the code. I have provided my own much simple processing in the link: [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/2w3t6gz.jpg[/IMG]. Its effect on the Lena is alot better, but it is not an edge detector. Just a noise reductive image sharpener.

Comment: I will read the article about anisotropic diffusion. Besides, @Drazick , the code in github has error when the image is larger than about 328*228, but the result of small picture is good. Thank you very much for your enthusiastic reply.

Comment: @Kuo, Are you sure? Could you tell me what the error is? Is it Memory related? Are you on Windows 32 Bit?

Comment: Updated my answer once more.

Comment: @Drazick , the error "is Attempted to access mInputImage(NaN,NaN); index must be a positive integer or
logical." 
"Error in ApplyImageLineIntegralConvolution (line 47) val = val + mInputImage(cy, cx);" "Error in FastAnisotropicCurvaturePreservingSmoothing (line 62)
    mOutputImage = mOutputImage+ApplyImageLineIntegralConvolution(mInputImage, tTensorField, mLength, stepSize);" "Error in FastAnisotropicCurvaturePreservingSmoothingDemo (line 59)
[ mOutputImage ] = FastAnisotropicCurvaturePreservingSmoothing(mInputImage, ..."

Comment: My Operating System is Win8 64bit

Comment: Could you open an issue in GitHub and post the image you tries it on and the exact call to the function? Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

I would not suggest an equalization as the first step.
Go with noise reduction.

[image]

Comment: So, you think that I need to reduce the noise first? Then implement histogram equalization?

Comment: yes reduce the noice first. A blind histogram equalization may or may not improve your edges. So you better improve your edges adaptively.

Comment: When does edge sharpening reduce the noise?

Comment: Is there any method that I can use to enhance my edge? I have tried highboost filtering, but in low contrast condition, highboost filtering can't perform well.

Comment: @tbirdal noise is reduced before edge is sharpened, in fact my algorithm is a space-variant nonlinear edge adaptive image sharpener. Its main purpose is to produce visually high quality sharp images while still preserving texture and yet not amplifiying noise. However, since it tries to protect textures from being washed out by the noise reduction, it may not produce desired result for all types of noises.

Comment: @Kuo edge enhancement may not be exactly what you are looking for, because your logo's edge is already very well defined. Your image's problem is inadequate illumination and also the vehicle's paint creates in noise like texture. That anisotropic diffusion filter seems to reduce that background excellently. And essentially gives you what you need. But in any case for edge enhancement I suggest you have a look at edge adaptive lowpass and highpass filters for a simplest treatments. Those edges will generally be detected by their local behaviour.

Comment: But, in some cases, the contrast is very low. I need to improve the quality of the edge. Besides, why inadequate illumination can cause noise like texture?

Comment: @Kuo noisy texturing is not because of wrong illumination, it is because of the paint used on the car. Illumination however, is the prime factor which greatly affects every aspect of imaging chain. In your case inadequate illumination causes uneven brightness, excessive highlights etc over the image. So you better apply best illuminants. On the other hand, if your aim is to cut that logo using automatic algorithms as if you were doing it on Photoshop using your mouse, you better think twice ;)

Comment: Exactly, my aim is to cut that logo using automatic algorithm. I am confused by different illumination condition.